# Naming strategy of columns in spring boot 2

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

how can I configure spring to using underscore in columns without explicitly defined in `@Column`? For instance if I have column in entity like this:

```
@LastModifiedBy
private String changedBy;
```

I want to map it to physical column in database which is `changed_by`

I tried to configure it with property `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy` to **SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy** or **PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl** but I always got exception `ERROR: column "changedby" of relation "xxxx" does not exist`

Comment: SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy does what you want. https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-field-naming-spring-boot

Answer (score 3):

In my setup (`Postgres`, `Flyway`), I achieve this using the `hybernate-types` package: https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types . This will give you a ready-to-use implementation for the naming strategy: `CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNamingStrategy`

You can configure this in XML like this:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.physical_naming_strategy"
value="com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.util.CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNamingStrategy"/>
```

Alternatively, you can configure it in code (Kotlin in my case):

```
@Bean
fun entityManagerFactory(): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
    val jpaProperties = Properties().apply {
        put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNamingStrategy::class.java.canonicalName)
        // ....
    }
    return LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean().apply {
        setJpaProperties(properties)
        // ....
    }
```

See also https://vladmihalcea.com/map-camel-case-properties-snake-case-column-names-hibernate/ for further information.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [custom naming for snake case](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-naming-strategy)

> we can tell Hibernate to use our new strategy:
>
> ```
> hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=com.baeldung.hibernate.namingstrategy.CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy
>
> public class CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy implements PhysicalNamingStrategy {     
>     @Override
>     public Identifier toPhysicalCatalogName(final Identifier identifier, final JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnv) {
>         return convertToSnakeCase(identifier);
>     }     
>     @Override
>     public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(final Identifier identifier, final JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnv) {
>         return convertToSnakeCase(identifier);
>     }     
>     @Override
>     public Identifier toPhysicalSchemaName(final Identifier identifier, final JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnv) {
>         return convertToSnakeCase(identifier);
>     }     
>     @Override
>     public Identifier toPhysicalSequenceName(final Identifier identifier, final JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnv) {
>         return convertToSnakeCase(identifier);
>     }     
>     @Override
>     public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(final Identifier identifier, final JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnv) {
>         return convertToSnakeCase(identifier);
>     }     
>     private Identifier convertToSnakeCase(final Identifier identifier) {
>         final String regex = "([a-z])([A-Z])";
>         final String replacement = "$1_$2";
>         final String newName = identifier.getText()
>           .replaceAll(regex, replacement)
>           .toLowerCase();
>         return Identifier.toIdentifier(newName);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: not works for me .. I don't understand. I also create it as bean and mark it as primary, but when I run in debug mode, my break point was hit in different strategy implementation

Comment: @DenisStephanov do you use application.properties? is there single row of `hibernate.physical_naming_strategy`?

Comment: Don't forget to update application.properties to point to new class: `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=path.to.package.CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [@Column](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) to manually specify the name of your column:

```
     @LastModifiedBy
     @Column(name="changed_by")
     private String changedBy;
```

Comment: I know but I want avoid it because I would change it in whole application. In boot 1.5 we had mapped camel case to snake automatically